# How to pass a formula as an argument to a function in r?

Tags: r, formula

How do I pass a formula as an argument in R?

The code below works for the first two cases, but when I pass in the formula, I get an error:  `Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula, weights = weights, na.action = na.omit,  :   invalid type (closure) for variable '(weights)'`

```r
makeModel<-function(formula,weights) {
    m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = weights)
    return(m);
}
run<-function(t) {
    f<-formula(t$y~t$x+t$r)
    m <- lm(t$y~t$x+t$r, na.action = na.omit, weights = t$size)
    m <- lm(f, na.action = na.omit, weights = t$size)
    m <- makeModels(f,t$size)    
}
l<-20
x<-seq(0,1,1/l)
y<-sqrt(x)
r=round(runif(n=length(x),min=0,max=.8))
n<-1:(l+1)
size=n/sum(n)
t<-data.frame(x,y,r,n,size)
run(t)
```

edit 1: this code:

```
makeModel<-function(formula,weights,t) {
    print(class(weights))
    m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = weights,data=t)
    return(m);
}
run<-function(t) {
    f<-formula(y~x+r)
    f <- as.formula("t$y~t$x+t$r")
    m <- lm(y~x+r, na.action = na.omit, weights = t$size,data=t)
    m <- lm(f, na.action = na.omit, weights = t$size,data=t)
    m <- makeModel(f,t$size,t)    
}
```

produces:

Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula, data = t, weights = weights,  : 
  invalid type (closure) for variable '(weights)'

edit 2: works:

```
makeModel <- function(formula, data) {
    # size is looked in data first, which is why this works
    m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = size, data =  data) # works
    #m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = data$size, data =  data) # fails!
    return(m)
}
```

r is strange!

Does anyone know why the line with: weights=data$size fails?

Edit 3: Got: weights=data$size to work.

```
makeModel<-function(formula,w,data) {
    print(class(weights))
    m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = size, data =  data) # works
    m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = data$size, data =  data) #works
    m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = w,data=data) # fails
    return(m);
}
run<-function(data) {
    f<-formula(y~x+r)
    #f <- as.formula("t$y~t$x+t$r")
    m <- lm(y~x+r, na.action = na.omit, weights = data$size,data=data)
    m <- lm(f, na.action = na.omit, weights = data$size,data=data)
    m <- makeModel(f,data$size,data)    
}
```

The last one fails with a:  Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'w' not found

Comment: does not seem to work. see edit

Comment: Regarding your new question then do see my post where I stress that it is the environment in which you assign the formula that makes the difference.

Comment: yes, but it was very hard to understand. and i missed the part about using t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See examples in `?as.formula`. You should not be explicitly calling variables from their variable names. The formula should be an abstract, and `lm` will know which variables to pull from `data`, which you should specify.

```
makeModels <- function(formula, data) {
  # size is looked in data first, which is why this works
  m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = size, data =  data)
  return(m)
}

run <- function(t) {
  f <- formula(y ~ x + r)
  m1 <- lm(formula = f, na.action = na.omit, weights = size, data = t)
  m2 <- makeModels(formula = f, data = t)
  return(list(m1, m2))
}

l<-20
x<-seq(0,1,1/l)
y<-sqrt(x)
r=round(runif(n = length(x), min = 0, max = 0.8))
n<-1:(l+1)
size=n/sum(n)
t<-data.frame(x,y,r,n,size)
run(t)

[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = f, data = t, weights = t$size, na.action = na.omit)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x            r  
   0.327154     0.706553    -0.008167  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = data, weights = size, na.action = na.omit)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x            r  
   0.327154     0.706553    -0.008167
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid assigning an object called `t` which coincides with the transpose function. Looking at the traceback yields

```r
makeModel<-function(formula,weights) {
  m <- lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = weights)
  return(m)
}
run<-function(x) {
  f<-formula(x$y~x$x+x$r)
  m <- lm(x$y~x$x+x$r, na.action = na.omit, weights = x$size)
  m <- lm(f, na.action = na.omit, weights = x$size)
  m <- makeModel(f,x$size)    
}
l<-20
x<-seq(0,1,1/l)
y<-sqrt(x)
r=round(runif(n=length(x),min=0,max=.8))
n<-1:(l+1)
size=n/sum(n)
x<-data.frame(x,y,r,n,size)
run(x)
#R Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula, weights = weights, na.action = na.omit,  : 
#R    invalid type (closure) for variable '(weights)'
traceback()
#R 7: model.frame.default(formula = formula, weights = weights, na.action = na.omit, 
#R                        drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
#R 6: stats::model.frame(formula = formula, weights = weights, na.action = na.omit, 
#R                       drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
#R 5: eval(mf, parent.frame())
#R 4: eval(mf, parent.frame())
#R 3: lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = weights) at #3
#R 2: makeModel(f, x$size) at #5
#R 1: run(t)
```

Now `debug(model.frame.default)` shows that [this  line](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/stats/R/models.R#L488) is where it goes wrong due to [these line](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/stats/R/models.R#L445-L446) and [this line](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/stats/R/models.R#L454). The reason is that it calls

```r
eval(list(weights = weights), environment(formula), environment(formula))
```

and there is no `weights` object assigned in the `run` environment (the environment where the formula is assigned) so instead it yields `stats::weights`. Three solutions are

```r
makeModel <- function(formula, weights) {
  environment(formula) <- environment()
  lm(formula, na.action = na.omit, weights = weights)
}
run<-function(x) {
  f <- x$y ~ x$x + x$r
  makeModel(f, x$size)  
}
x1 <- run(x)

makeModel <- function(formula, weights) {
  cl <- match.call()
  cl[[1L]] <- quote(lm)
  cl$na.action <- quote(na.omit)
  eval(cl, parent.frame())
}
run<-function(x) {
  f <- x$y ~ x$x + x$r
  makeModel(f, x$size)  
}
x2 <- run(x)

makeModel <- function(formula, weights, x) {
  cl <- match.call()
  cl[[1]] <- quote(lm)
  cl$x <- NULL
  cl[c("data", "formula", "na.action")] <- 
    list(quote(x), formula, quote(na.omit))
  eval(cl)
}
run<-function(x) {
  f <- y ~ x + r
  makeModel(f, size, x)  
}
x3 <- run(x)

stopifnot(all.equal(coef(x1), coef(x2)))
stopifnot(all.equal(coef(x1), coef(x3), check.attributes = FALSE))
```

As an example, the first solution above implies that

```r
eval(list(weights = weights), environment(formula), environment(formula))
```

succeeds since there is a `weights` object assigned in the environment of `formula`. The second solution makes a call in the `run` environment with `weights = x$size` and thus succeeds. The third one is like [Roman Luštrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52576795/5861244) though his solution is much more clean than the third I propose if you know that the `weights` argument is always the `size` column. Here the call is

```r
eval(list(weights = size), data, environment(formula))
```

which works since `size` is a column in `data`.

Comment: If user specified formula in the correct manner, all of this would go away. Even if formula needs to be constructed from variables, concatenating formula and wrapping it into `as.formula` would be much cleaner.

Comment: I agree that your solution is more nice if you know that the `weights` are called `size` always. What if the OP wants a function with arguments `function(formula, weights)` (as he post posted) and not `function(formula, data)`? However, I would prefer to avoid having formulas with `$` calls.